# Intuition behind log return of portfolio = weighted sum of log returns

Tags: mathematics, log-returns

Suppose we have $n$ assets, each of which has weight $w_i$ in the portfolio. The log return of asset $i$ is denoted by $r_i$.

What's the intuition why this holds approximately:

$$
ln \left( \sum_i w_i e^{r_{i,t}}\right) \approx \sum_i w_i r_{i,t}
$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The above relation really only approximately. If you consider arithmetic retunrs then it is exact.

For the approximation you just need to look at the Taylor series of the exponential:
$$
e^x = 1 + x + \text{ terms of higher order}.
$$
These terms of higher order ($x^2$ and $x^3$) become small if $x$ is much smaller than one - which holds true for returns.
Thus
$$
\sum_i w_i e^{r_i} \approx \sum_i w_i ( 1+ r_i) = 1 + \sum_i w_i r_i,
$$
if $\sum_i w_i = 1$.

Then conside that  $\ln(1+x) \approx x$ (you can check [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ln%281%2Bx%29)) and you are done:

$$
\ln \left(1 + \sum_i w_i r_i \right) \approx \sum_i w_i r_i.
$$

Comment: Just to add that the approximation works well for `x` within +-10% - see e.g. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B%7BExp%5Bx%5D,+1+%2B+x%7D,+%7Bx,+-0.15,+0.15%7D%5D